# How to stop setState when called from displaying black screen with loading widget in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, state-management

I am trying to code in my Flutter app a simple functionality that when a user clicks on an object it will change colors. I do this with the following code:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
  setState(() {
   computer = !computer;
    });
  },
  child: SubjectCard(subject: computer, index: 4),
),


class SubjectCard extends StatelessWidget {

  var subject;
  int index;

  SubjectCard({this.subject, this.index});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          color: subject == true ? categories[index].color.withOpacity(1) : categories[index].color.withOpacity(0.55),
          // color: pressAttention0 == true ? categories[1].color.withOpacity(1) : categories[1].color.withOpacity(0.55),
        ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircleNumber(index: index + 1),
                  Container(
                    width: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container()
              ),
              Text(
                categories[index].name,
                style: kTitleTextCardStyle,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 2),
              Text(
                '${categories[index].numOfTutors} Tutors',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
                         );
  }
}
```

The part where I change colors is with this line of code :

```
color: subject == true ? categories[index].color.withOpacity(1) : categories[index].color.withOpacity(0.55),
```

However whenever a user clicks on the object the color changes (which is what I want) but the whole app reloads and the user is momentarily sent to a black screen with a large blue loading indicator. I did not code this in and am unsure why this is happening. The screen is annoying and I want to get rid of it and instead have the app change the color of the object without them noticing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure out why this happens? I have the exact same problem, sometimes when routing and sometimes calling SetState().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging i found out why this happen to me and it's maybe not the same issue as you had but the visual result is the same. I might as well describe what caused the problem in my scenario and it was related to using FutureBuilder in a statefulWidget.

Reading the second paragraph [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

The solution here would be to declare your Future as a field (variable) in the state class and set it in `initState` instead of directly in the build section, see example below.

```
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Future<void> _initializeWidgetFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeWidgetFuture = MyService.GetSomeData(); // Set the future here!!
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
      future: _initializeWidgetFuture, // Don't call MyService.GetSomeData() here!!
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            return Text("Component initalized");
          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```